# Can't return value of a position in a array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have been looking for a way of returning the value of a string by calling it's position but everytime the "".indexOf(i); always return the value of "i" instead of the position "i".

So I always end up having -1 has the innerHTML... I would need to have descs and prices match the "i" position in their array. I really need help, thanks alot !!

```
codes = [46382,35661,23227,33221,12678,35672,77721,22373,22112,33234,55236,67873,17634,62378,36778,36783,36773,67844,36783,78582];  

prices = [2.98,0.67,0.99,29.99,26.97,351.00,501.21,131.16,5.72,9.93,5.36,30.80,30.80,2.00,18.49,5.28,3.00,23.91,16.47,7.79];

function refreshSequence (n) {

            var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("article_code_1").value);
            document.getElementById("article_qte_1").value = 1;
            for(i=0; i<codes.indexOf(x); i++) {
                document.getElementById("article_description_1").innerHTML = descs.indexOf(i);
                document.getElementById("article_prix_unit_1").innerHTML = prices.indexOf(i);
            }

        }
```

Comment: It's really not obvious what your problem is. `console.log(i)` and see that it's an index not the value.

Comment: to access an element in an array by it's index, use `prices[i]`

Comment: Also, why are you updating innerHTML multiple times in a for loop? Perhaps you can take the for loop out and just have `document.getElementById("article_description_1").innerHTML = descs[codes.indexOf(x)];` and `document.getElementById("article_prix_unit_1").innerHTML = prices[codes.indexOf(x)];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `indexOf()` Method returns the index of a specific element in an array. If you want to return an element given an index you simply use `array[index]` for example

```
var a = ['hey', 'there',];
a[1] // this returns 'there'
a[0] // this returns 'hey'
```

Comment: ok, I was just calling a indexOf() instead of the : a[1] !! thanks alot, sorry I am new to javascript.

Comment: No problem at all, we've all been there.